# Facebook Login within a modal using Omniauth, Ajax and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth, warden

Currently I am working on enabling sign in's via social networks(in this case facebook) from within a modal and using omniauth. Because there are certain dom changes that need to happen on success, I wanted to use an ajax call as well.

My actual click function in coffeescript is:

```
(".sign-sns .facebook").click (e) ->
    FB.login (response) ->
      if response.authResponse
        $.post("/auth/facebook/callback")
        .done (response) ->
          SOME_CALLBACKS_HERE
        .fail (response) ->
          DISPLAY_SOME_ERROR
```

However, when it makes the ajax request, it never actually hits the controller action set in the routes. If I was to make a manual get or post as a url it would work fine, but trying to  skip that and post directly to the callback route doesn't seem to be working.

I have also tried another method where I post to the url that I would link as such:

```
(".sign-sns .facebook").click (e) ->
  $.post("/auth/facebook?path=signup")
  .done (response) ->
    SOME_CALLBACKS_HERE
  .fail (response) ->
    DISPLAY_SOME_ERROR
```

which would hit my controller, but then when I tried to authenticate via warden, would have no omniauth params set. So I am kinda stuck. Any one have an idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I threw this in my app and it worked, but my `$.post` url is `"/users/auth/facebook/callback"`.  If I intentionally put in a bad URL, and thus a 404, `.fail` fires.  I'm sure you've placed break points on both `.done` and `.fail` to see which are firing?  

Don't you also need to pass in FB response data via Query string?  Otherwise, anyone could post to your URL and "authenticate" themselves.

Comment: Just FYI, I didn't test, nor use, this auth flow.  I simply tested the function to ensure callbacks were getting handled.  E.g I was already logged when I fired it.  My flow is server side, so I can't test your entire flow.  I'm a canvas app, so I have to user server side.  You're not a canvas app are you?

`On Canvas, if the user is 'unknown' (that is, when the login status == 'unknown'), do not use the JS SDK to sign in the user, instead do a full redirect of the page to the oauth dialog so that we get a consistent state.`

Comment: I'm not using canvas no. My issue is with trying to get my ajax request to properly work as if I had done it via a link. The latter code snipper, just eats up all the redirects that facebook and omniauth do.